# Inverse of $I_{n}+VV^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra

The goal is to show that the inverse of $I_{n}+VV^{T}$ is $I_{n}-\frac{VV^{T}}{1+V^{T}V}$, where $V$ is an $n$-by-$1$ vector. Here is my work so far:

Goal: $(I_{n}+VV^{T})(I_{n}-\frac{VV^{T}}{1+V^{T}V})=I_{n}+VV^{T}-\frac{VV^{T}}{1+V^{T}V}-\frac{(VV^{T})^{2}}{1+V^{T}V}=I_{n}$,

meaning that $VV^{T}-\frac{VV^{T}}{1+V^{T}V}-\frac{(VV^{T})^{2}}{1+V^{T}V} = 0$

so $VV^{T}=\frac{VV^{T}+(VV^{T})^{2}}{1+V^{T}V}$

so $VV^{T}+VV^{T}(V^TV)=VV^T+(VV^T)^{2}$

so $VV^{T}(V^TV)=(VV^T)^{2}$

However, I don't understand why this must be true, since $V^TV$ is a scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
VV^T(V^TV) = V(V^TV)V^T = (VV^T)(VV^T) = (VV^T)^2.
$$

Comment: I see you could move $(V^TV)$ like that because it's a scalar